# Using Angular js with taglibs

Tags: java, javascript, taglib, angularjs

I'm using the Stripes MVC text tag, but get an exception if I add Angular's ng-model to it because the attribute obviously isn't supported in the taglib.  Does anybody know best practices for handling this situation?

```
<s:text name="name" ng-model="yourName" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the Stripe's tag libraries but from what I can see looking at their documentation (http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Tag+Library+Doc) Stripes MVC does include a version of their tlds where you are allowed to use so called "dynamic attributes":

> However with the advent of AJAX and JavaScript libraries it is
>   sometimes desirable to use non-HTML attributes in HTML tags. For the
>   reasons outlined above Stripes includes two slightly different TLDs
>   that can be used. The standard one does not allow dynamic attributes
>   in HTML tags and should be used in most cases. The second one allows
>   dynamic attributes. It is possible (even recommended) to use both TLDs
>   in one page. Doing so will allow the standard library to be used where
>   possible, and the dynamic attribute one only where absolutely
>   necessary. E.g.:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="d" uri="http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes-dynattr.tld" %>

<s:form action="/my/NewsSearch.action">
    <s:text name="keywords"/>
    <d:text name="publicationDate" dojoType="calendar"/>
    <s:submit name="search"/>
</s:form>
```

So I guess you should simply import the 'dynamic' version of the tlds and use it like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="d" uri="http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes-dynattr.tld" %>

<d:text name="name" ng-model="yourName" />
```